# How to run this bash command with EOF inside parantheses?

Tags: bash, shell

I have this curl command:

```
curl -X POST "https://api.datadoghq.com/api/v1/synthetics/tests/trigger" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-H "DD-API-KEY: xxx" \
-H "DD-APPLICATION-KEY: yyy" \
-d @- << EOF
{
  "tests": [
    {
      "public_id": "123-far-456"
    }
  ]
}
EOF
```

which I want to run inside `()` to get the result in to a variable.
Like this:

```
curl_response=$(curl -X POST "https://api.datadoghq.com/api/v1/synthetics/tests/trigger" \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -H "DD-API-KEY: xxx" \
    -H "DD-APPLICATION-KEY: yyy" \
    -d @- << EOF
    {
      "tests": [
        {
          "public_id": "123-far-456"
        }
      ]
    }
    EOF)
```

How can I escape `EOF` to run this?
I tried `-d @- << datadog.json` but doesn't work.

Comment: final `EOF` must be alone at start of line

Comment: why not `... -d @datadog.json` ?

Comment: To add to what @jhnc said, put the closing parenthesis on the next line. `EOF` must be on its own, except with `<<-EOF` which will strip indenting tabs (not spaces). Also, unless you need variable expansion, use quoted `<<-"EOF"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The token `EOF` has to be on a line of its own, and not start with any whitespace:

```
curl_response=$(curl -X POST "https://api.datadoghq.com/api/v1/synthetics/tests/trigger" \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -H "DD-API-KEY: xxx" \
    -H "DD-APPLICATION-KEY: yyy" \
    -d @- << EOF
    {
      "tests": [
        {
          "public_id": "123-far-456"
        }
      ]
    }
EOF
)
```

Yeah, it's ugly. If you want pretty, don't use bash ;)

> I tried `-d @- << datadog.json` but doesn't work.

When redirecting from a file, use single `<`. But in this case, `curl` allows you to do simply `-d @datadog.json` to read from the file without any shell magic.